# Magento2.4.5: Order total showing of a same product with diffrent size options in order detail page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

**Related Issue**

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30342

**you can check that issue on GitHub as a reference for understanding.**

> 

you can see from the image that the customer placed an order for two different sizes of the same product but somehow a row got created the first row contains the sum of **Subtotal,    Tax Amount,     Row Total** of below these size options. This is not Magento behaviour and I don't understand how it happens
does anyone have any idea why the third row got created?
[image]

**as you can see the first row contains the sum values of below these two rows, as magento default behaviour the first row shouldnt have created in the first place.**

Answer (score 1):

I became curious too about this and tried to replicate it.

I had no chance to end up with the same issue, all the time the checkout being exactly on products ordered as expected.

Are you sure you are not using any extra extension, theme or code that changes the Shopping cart?

Would you try with all the extras non essential off to see how it works, and mainly try it on default Luma theme to see that your custom theme is not messing this?